# Load and Post models to and from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to load a model from my Asp.Net Web API controller, onto my ViewModel (which contains a model with Lists containing Lists.. so quite complex).

The .Net model is:

```
public class PlateTemplateExtendedDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal Height { get; set; }
        public decimal Width { get; set; }
        public List<PlateTemplateGroupDto> PlateTemplateGroups { get; set; } = new List<PlateTemplateGroupDto>();

    }
```

The List item in that class is declared as:

```
  public class PlateTemplateGroupDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<PlateTemplateGroupComponentDto> Components { get; set; } = new List<PlateTemplateGroupComponentDto>();

    }
```

And then within THAT list, as an object:

```
public class PlateTemplateGroupComponentDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PlateTemplateGroupId { get; set; }
        public int GroupComponentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string GroupComponentType { get; set; }
        public int EntryDisplayOrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's some of my View Model. 'Data' is the field I want to hold my data model in, and post it back.

```
function TemplateViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Data = ko.observable();

    self.TemplateId = ko.observable($("#InputTemplateId").val());
    self.CreateMode = ko.observable(!!self.TemplateId() == false);


    self.loadData = function () {
        $.get("/api/Template/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
            alert(self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups().length);
        });
    }


    self.save = function () {
        var data = ko.mapping.toJS(self.TemplateGroups);
        $.post("/api/Template/Save", data).done(function (result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    };

    if (!self.CreateMode()) {
        self.loadData();
    }

}
```

The Alert after the load works... and if I break into the code, I can see that Data holds the model I expect.

However, when I try use it on the view, it fails:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-bind="foreach: Data().PlateTemplateGroups()">
                <li data-bind="css: {active: $index()==0}"><a data-toggle="tab" data-bind="attr: {href: ('#tabId' + $index())}"><span data-bind="text: Description"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Nothing happens. Is this because something isn't initialised yet? Is it even possible to do this? There is an error in the console window:

> Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function
>   (){return Data().PlateTemplateGroups() }" Message: Cannot read
>   property 'PlateTemplateGroups' of undefined

In the debugger, if I breakpoint after the Load Data... I see this: 
[image]

In fact, straight after loading from the api call, I can see all the data in the model:

self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups()[0].Components()

It shows the first item in the PlateTemplateGroups list, and I can see the items in 'Components' (which is a list too. It all seems observable, as I access them as functions.

My view model applybindings happens at the end of my js file:

```
function PlateTemplateViewModel() {
    var self = this;
....
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new PlateTemplateViewModel(), $("#plateTemplate")[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have errors in browser console? Do you sure that PlateTemplateGroups is observable field?

Please show us api response example and viewModel state before render

```
function TemplateViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Data = ko.observable({PlateTemplateGroups: ko.observableArray()});
 //....
```

Execution plan of your code:
call `new TemplateViewModel()`,
      call `self.loadData`
call `applyBindings // in this moment data didn't return from the server and ko throw error`,
call 'done' callback of loadData function

You should pre init viewModel or call applyBinding as callback:

```
 self.loadData = function (callback) {
        $.get("/api/Template/Get", { id: self.TemplateId() }).done(function (data) {
            self.Data(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
            alert(self.Data().PlateTemplateGroups().length);

            if(typeof callback === 'function')
                callback();
        });
    }
```

not call loadData in view model constructor

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = new PlateTemplateViewModel();
    if (!viewModel.CreateMode()) {
        viewModel.loadData(function(){
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $("#plateTemplate")[0]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The error in the console is "Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return Data().PlateTemplateGroups() }"
Message: Cannot read property 'PlateTemplateGroups' of undefined". Sorry, I should have put that.

Comment: Do you can to show me where you call applyBindings method?

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: $.get is async function. Do you sure that ko.applyBindings execute after data returned from the server?

You can use preinit for PlateTemplateGroups (added to the answer)

Comment: Wow, @RomanKiyashev ! That worked! I have no idea what you did, but the screen now loads. But some items didn't load. The object that I am loading in is a class with 4 items (strings and ints), as well as a List<PlateTemplateGroup>. And a PlateTemplateGroup contains a List<Component>. So that two lists have loaded... But the items in the containing object didn;t load.

Comment: I added the .Net class declaration to try explain better the data structure. There's 3 classes involved. A root class, containing some fields and a List...

Comment: Try to call applyBindings after loadData (added to answer) and read about custom mappings http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148827/discussion-between-craig-and-roman-kiyashev).